# Is it possible using isotope item as a trigger to hiddien items?

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have a customer layout that will use Isotop (I think it is the only plugin that can do what I need).
It is a portfolio and the layout asks for ajax loading content when an item is clicked.
I know how to load this through simple jquery load function, but I wonder if this is not actually a built in feature of Isotop?
If yes' how would I do that?
Thanks,
Yehuda

Answer (score 0):

OK, this seems to work for me. I hope to get better answer than that, though.

-- HTML --

```
<div id="portfolio1" class="element Packaging Mitug   " data-symbol="Hg" data-category="Packaging">
<a href="#"><img src="/Portals/0/images/portfolio/p6_250x250_off.jpg" /></a>
<p class="portfolioItemTtl"><a href="#">פורטפוליו 1</a></p>
 <div  class="portfolio1Details" id="portfolio1Details"></div>  
 <div id="portfolio1detailes" class="portfolio1detailes"></div>
```

-- the Isotope script here --

-- Then add something like this -- 
-- Note the reLayout befor the jQuery Load --

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#portfolio1').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#portfolio1').css('width','100%');
        $('#portfolio1').css('height','800px');
        $('#portfolio1 a img').css('display','none');
        $('#isoTopContainer').isotope('reLayout');
        $('#portfolio1').load('demo_test.txt');
        $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#portfolio2detailes").offset().top
         }, 1000);
    });
});

</script>
```